# Passing select values between 2 ejs files

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have the following select values in my upload.ejs file:

```
  <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="category" action="/readCategory" method="post" >
            <option value="Agriculture, Food & Natural Resources">Agriculture, Food & Natural Resources</option>
            <option value="Architecture & Construction">Architecture & Construction</option>
            <option value="Arts, Audio/Video Technology & Communications">Arts, Audio/Video Technology & Communications</option>
            <option value="Business Management and Administration">Business Management and Administration</option>
            <option value="Education and Training">Education and Training</option>
            <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
            <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
            <option value="Government and Public Administration">Government and Public Administration</option>
            <option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
            <option value="Hospitality and Tourism">Hospitality and Tourism</option>
            <option value="Human Services">Human Services</option>
            <option value="IT (Information Technology)">IT (Information Technology)</option>
            <option value="Law, Public Safety, Corrections & Security">Law, Public Safety, Corrections & Security</option>
            <option value="Manpower & Services">Manpower & Services</option>
            <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
            <option value="Marketing, Sales & Services">Marketing, Sales & Services</option>
            <option value="Science, Technology & Mathematics">Science, Technology & Mathematics</option>
            <option value="Transportation, Distribution & Logistics">Transportation, Distribution & Logistics</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

I need to read these values & display them as a  heading in my index.ejs file:

```
<div class="container my-4">
    <h2><%=  %></h2>
```

I have tried it out in many ways like in my server.js like:

```
app.post("/readCategory", function(request, result){
  result.render("index", {
    "categories": request.body.category

  });

});
```

and used categories in my h2 heading in index.html file but nothing seems to work.

Does somebody have a solution for this?

Comment: Hi top talent, can you let me know how to use the categories variable in index.ejs to display all the values. Thanks in advance

Comment: <% categories.forEach(function(values){ %>
    7|     <h2> <%values.value%> </h2>
    8|     <% })%>
    9| 

categories is not defined